# Why is my output wrong?

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;

    const double COUNTY_TAX = 0.02;
    const double STATE_TAX = 0.04;
    double totalSales;
    void countyTax(double newCountyTax);
    void stateTax(double newStateTax);
    void total(double newTotal);

    int main ()
    {

        cout << "Please enter the total dollar amount of sales: $";
        cin >> totalSales;

        countyTax(1);
        stateTax(1);
        total(1);

        return 0;   
    }

    void countyTax(double newCountyTax)
    {
        double newCountyTaxA;

        newCountyTaxA = totalSales * COUNTY_TAX;

        cout << "The county tax is: $" << newCountyTaxA << endl;

    }

    void stateTax(double newStateTax)
    {

        double newStateTaxA;

        newStateTaxA = totalSales * STATE_TAX;

        cout << "The State tax is: $" << newStateTaxA << endl;

    }

    void total(double newTotal)
    {
        double newTotalA, newStateTaxA, newCountyTaxA;

        newTotalA = newStateTaxA + newCountyTaxA;

        cout << "The total is: $" << newTotalA << endl;

    }
```

hello guys! I am getting into modules in C++ and the above code compiles correctly but I can't seem to figure out why my output is wonky. I get the county tax and state tax to show properly but when the total shows I get "$nan" i was wondering if i could get some feedback on this? does it possibly have to do with the fact that within the module i am not using any global variables like i do with the `totalSales` and `COUNTY_TAX` and `SALES_TAX` and that when i declare `newTotalA` `newStateTaxA` `newCountyTaxA` they are declared but not assigned? just a tad confused here..THANKS!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: From the [ask] your were told to read: *"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"* Actual title: *"Why is my output wrong?"* Come on...

Comment: apologies senpai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variables `newStateTaxA` and `newCountyTaxA` that are created and computed in `countyTax` and `stateTax` are local to those functions. Once the functions complete, those variables, and the values they contain, go away. In `total` you create new local variables with the same names. These have no relationship with the previously defined variables, apart from sharing names, and will not store the values previously computed in the other two functions.

The easiest solution, although not considered the most robust, is to create the two variables at the global scope, along with `totalSales` so that the values that they are assigned to in the two functions persist.

If you do not wish to use global variables (which I also don't care to use), you can declare them in your main function, and modify your other functions to return the calculated values:

```
double countyTax(double newCountyTax)
{
    double newCountyTaxA;

   newCountyTaxA = totalSales * COUNTY_TAX;

   cout << "The county tax is: $" << newCountyTaxA << endl;

   return newCountytaxA;
}
```

The calls in `main()` would then read:

```
newCountyTaxA = countyTax(1);
```

Comment: would it be less constructive if i just placed all the calculations i want to do in one module so that they are all in the same scope, maintaining my want to have them not be global, and i can still call the module in main?

Comment: @AlexChapman I updated to show an alternative to all global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your are doing a fundamental mistake here in the following code :

```
void total(double newTotal)
{
    double newTotalA, newStateTaxA, newCountyTaxA;

    newTotalA = newStateTaxA + newCountyTaxA;

    cout << "The total is: $" << newTotalA << endl;

}
```

The Variables that you have created here "newStateTaxA", and "newCountyTaxA" does not have any relation to the other variables that you have created and assigned in the other methods, they are local for each method. You need to either make them global or return valued from those functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double COUNTY_TAX = 0.02;
const double STATE_TAX = 0.04;
double totalSales;
void Taxes();

int main ()
{

    cout << "Please enter the total dollar amount of sales: $";
    cin >> totalSales;

    Taxes();

    return 0;   
}

void Taxes()
{
    double countyTax, stateTax, total;

    countyTax = totalSales * COUNTY_TAX;
    stateTax = totalSales * STATE_TAX;
    total = countyTax + stateTax;

    cout << "The County Tax is: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << countyTax << endl;
    cout << "The State Tax is: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << stateTax << endl;
    cout << "The total is: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << total << endl;
}
```

here is what I came up with. Everything works and outputs as desired. I guess now I am wondering if this type of setup with one module and multiple calculations inside it considered good programming?